# Android screen flickering when navigating to the new activity with auto-rotation disabled

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-layout, android-activity

I have set orientation programmatically to landscape for tablets and portrait for phones.

[image]

The issue is that when navigating on **tablet** from one activity to another, with **auto-rotation disabled** and **in portrait mode** the screen is flickering. First, it navigates to the new activity in portrait mode and then changes to landscape which is not the output I would want.

I've tried adding to the manifest

```
android:screenOrientation="locked"
android:screenOrientation="nosensor"
android:screenOrientation="sensor"
```

and in activity for tablets I've set

```
setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR);
```

Which doesn't flicker, but still its not what I want.

Expected outcome is for phones to stay as portrait mode and tablet as landscape. I think that the main issue is with system auto-rotate setting as disabled, because when it's enabled and I try to navigate from one activity to another, the screens doesn't flick and just stay as either portrait or landscape.

I think I could use

```
Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.ACCELEROMETER_ROTATION, 1);
```

but then I need settings write permissions, which should be enabled by the user and I want to know if somehow I can omit that

Comment: personally I've never found a solution for that... ended up with building two separated APKs (flavors), with `horizontal` and `vertical` orientation set for all activities in manifest, just for that reason... Looks like `Activity` will always start in fixed or physical device orientation (sensor), you can't decide programmatically before it is actually launched...

Comment: so Manifest decides always afaik... btw. never tried solution with `Settings.System`, does it work? my app will get needed perm for sure

Comment: I mean it did work for me, but I might have different scenario thank Yours. I've added writing permission in manifest and in application settings and it worked. In my case, if rotation is turned on, everything works as expected and the screen doesnt flicker

Comment: but this `Setting` is setting rotation fixed for "whole device"? so if user leave app and moves to other (which e.g. support sensor) then this other won't change orientation even when device's will be opposite? (well, this might be detected, do have an idea, switching in runtime)